# Why are UK MPs targeting the prime minister and not the deal?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, conservative-party, theresa-may

Given that the Prime Minister's activity that has given rise to discontent in her own party, that any EU deal is subject to an imminent meaningful vote, and that no alternative candidate nor markedly better prospects for a deal resolving the NI backstop are obvious (the EU will hardly allow the UK a unilateral right to disengage unless the NI situation is resolved satisfactorily), what are the reasons why an MP would write to the 1922 Committee targeting the PM, rather than simply wait the extra day or two, and vote against her proposed deal?

Comment: The PM pulled the vote on the deal, so MPs couldn't target the deal.

Comment: Because the people who voted have no confidence in her capacity to get an improved deal

Comment: @Valorum - has anyone suggested that someone else might be able to get a significantly better deal, starting from where we now are? There seems to be conspicuous silence on that point. Apparently _nobody_ has confidence in _anyone's_ ability to get a significantly better deal as of now, than she herself could...?

Comment: @Stilez - I don't see why a competent negotiator wouldn't be able to improve the deal, whether it's Mrs May or someone else. Ultimately the EU wants a deal and is under significant pressure from the French, Germans, Irish, Spanish, etc to make sure that the UK doesn't go for a "no deal" exit (on WTO terms) that would potentially damage their economies. They also don't want Britain off on its own striking big new deals with the US and others that harm their own interests in the UK market.

Comment: Because the key point isn't a matter of degree, it's a yes/no issue which can't be kicked into the long grass. UK requires certainty that in a short time, there will be no customs boundary NI - mainland UK (national integrity). UK/Ireland requires no customs boundary interfering with NI/Eire (Good Friday peace agreement). EU cannot tolerate an EU/UK boundary _without_ a customs border (EU integrity). **Nobody** has suggested a solution that might work in a practical sense, hence the backstop, but that lasts indefinitely until an answer is reached. So unlike many cases, a better negotiator ...

Comment: ...might _not_ be able to do much. If they could, we surely would have heard voices reach agreement on both sides on the lines of "do this instead". But we haven't. See also my explanation _why_ it's so hard, and the NI/Eire background: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/34592/12228

Comment: Do you mean Conservative MPs specifically?  Labour is targeting for a change of government, for reasons that are not particularly hard to understand.

Comment: Because they're all massive hypocrites, which seems to be a requirement to call yourself a "conservative" politician nowadays.

Comment: @gerrit - only conservative MPs had a choice to vote against the PM as in the question, so that's  not relevant.

Comment: @gerrit Labour is *not* targeting for a change of government "right now", because if they lost touch with their pro-brexit electoral support base they would be wiped out as a national political party, and become about as practically relevant is the Liberals currently are. Their best chance is to keep their heads below the parapet till Brexit is legally over and done with, then mobilize the protest vote.

Comment: @alephzero Labour are not targeting for a change of government (no confidence vote) right now because they wouldn't succeed right now.  The irony is that the DUP would only support a no confidence vote if the Withdrawal Agreement was approved by Parliament, which would require at least some Labour support.  I think what they're targeting right now is entirely a matter of strategy, not one of desire.

Comment: @Stilez It is relevant, because all MPs *would* have had the opportunity to vote in a no confidence motion, if Labour had tabled one (which they didn't, for the reasons in my previous comment).

Comment: I don't believe Corbyn has any *strategy* whatever, beyond what is written in *Das Kapital.*

Comment: @alephzero Now that's not fair to Corbyn... he does refuse to consider a second referendum, even though that's the option that Labour supporters overwhelmingly prefer. His stubborn refusal to abide by the wishes of his supporters are also the reason why he'll never be in any position of power (or at least, I hope he won't - and I say that as a staunch Labour/Remain supporter).

Answer (score 91):

Brexit is a [submarine made out of cheese](https://twitter.com/hugorifkind/status/1072222352035987456).  Nobody sane at all thinks there is a good Brexit deal to be had.  (Every proposed "good Brexit deal" uniformly assumes they can dictate terms to the EU; that has not proven to be the case).

However, May has been forced (in order to become PM) to pretend there is a good cheese-submarine, and has in fact built a cheese-submarine.

This cheese-submarine is bad.  Of course it is, it is a submarine made out of cheese.  May has to pretend it isn't bad, because it is the result of 2 years of her leadership.

Everyone else is free to say "that cheese submarine is bad".  And they are right.  May has to say "no, it is a good cheese submarine", because it is the best cheese submarine one can expect (which isn't very good).

They also say "I can make a better cheese submarine".  Which is pretty much a lie; nobody actually thinks they can make a better one.  But, it is a lie you really cannot prove to be a lie **unless the person making the lie becomes prime minister**.

So by stating the clearly obvious "that cheese submarine is bad" and the impossible to disprove "I can make a better one", you position yourself (or your faction) to take over the UK government.  At that point, well, you sort of won already.  You'll probably try to ship a slightly modified cheese submarine, or maybe just let the cheese submarine sink; that is a problem for another day, after your faction is in control.

Defeating this particular cheese submarine (voting against the brexit deal) does not directly get you control of the UK.  In fact, once you do that, you might be obligated to propose a better cheese submarine solution, and that isn't a winning move.

Instead, point out the failures of May's cheese submarine (which are large, obvious and undefendable), and use that to unseat May, then get control yourself.  Once you have control, you could even just push forward May's cheese submarine as "the best you can do now that May wasted all that time" or whatever.  Or force a hard Brexit, and try to get the country to rally behind you.  Or negotiate more time from the EU.  Or revoke Brexit, then reinvoke Brexit to get yourself 2 more years of power and cheese-submarine making room.

The important part is, nobody actually has a better cheese submarine plan, but many people do want to have power and be in charge.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87214/discussion-on-answer-by-yakk-why-are-uk-mps-targeting-the-prime-minister-and-not).

Answer (score 27):

Theresa May isn't just being targeted over Brexit, though.

1. May called [snap elections in 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_United_Kingdom_general_election), in a bid to strengthen her hand. Instead, she lost seats and had to form a minority government propped up by a [confidence & supply agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative%E2%80%93DUP_agreement) with the [Democratic Unionist Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Unionist_Party) (where the Tories had outright control before). There's no question she did considerable political damage to herself at this point.
2. Brexit was always ill-defined during the Cameron era and May was not the chief proponent. Boris Johnson, the most outspoken proponent, [refused to run for PM](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/01/world/europe/boris-johnson-brexit-conservatives.html), likely because he knew the Brexit process would be messy (i.e. [how the Ireland/Northern Ireland border will work](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-politics-44615404))
3. May's negotiations over Brexit have not exactly been according to plan. The general idea was to get the UK out from under EU rule but [the current deal still leaves some EU power in place](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-46237012). As such, many in May's own party would not vote for it. Since her standing as PM is at stake, May postponed the vote to stave off a no-confidence vote but the political blood is in the water now.

Comment: Small correction to (1). No formal coallition similar to the [2010-2015 Conservative-Lib Dem Government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameron%E2%80%93Clegg_coalition) was formed. Instead Theresa May's post-2017 Government is a minority Conservative Gov which has support from Northern Ireland's Democratic Unionist Party in a [confidence & supply arrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative%E2%80%93DUP_agreement). The two parties do not have a formal plan for this Parliament together, but the DUP is expected to vote in favour of the Government in key votes such as the budget

Comment: It's not clear how point 2 relates to the question or to your opening sentence. My best guess is that you're saying May is being targeted because she is not pro-Brexit (although that would contradict the opening sentence).

Answer (score 20):

The PM has played this disastrously and is now under fire from at least three sources of opposition:

- the so-called "ERG", who believe that her deal is bad because it's not Brexity enough. They claim that a better deal with no backstop or a fake backstop is possible, despite all the evidence to the contrary. However, these people probably put in their letters long ago and there's only about 20 of them.
- the "moderate" faction, who believe that it might be possible to get a less bad deal by being less Brexity; the "Norway+" option. This also includes actual Remainers, although at this stage there's still no obvious Remain leadership candidate (Soubry? Hardly.)
- the "basic competence" discontents: the government was found to be in contempt of Parliament last week, which was an almost unprecedented condemnation. The government has also started trying to delay the vote on the deal. Cabinet ministers openly brief against their own government and vice versa. The basic ability of the government to function is in question and even Tories are going to get fed up of this after a while.

The deal is not *necessarily* up for immediate voting, I believe that May could delay it indefinitely because she has control of government "programme motions".

Comment: A good answer, though I think you should strike the word "trying" from the 3rd bullet. The Government has delayed the vote on the deal, removing it from the schedule at short notice. There's no trying, it's been booted down the road wasting yet more time.

The ERG's membership, while unpublished is estimated at over 50 by Wikipedia based on subscribers to the ERG's pooled services.

Comment: Why is Soubry hardly an obvious Remain leadership candidate?  She may not have enough support to win the leadership, but the party did "elect" a "remainer" last time. I would say Soubry has been posturing publicly enough recently to suggest she might be considering a leadership bid.

Comment: @TyHayes as a backbencher I don't believe she has enough popularity with the rest of the party, but anything could happen.

Comment: I'm not sure that politically May could delay the vote indefinitely. Per Article 50(s), if no deal is in place by 29 March 2019 (which is what would happen if Parliament does not vote on it) then we leave without a deal. For that to happen simply because the vote did not take place (as opposed to a deliberate choice to go for no-deal) would be a political disaster. A potential workaround would be to withdraw the notice and resubmit it (following from the recent ECJ ruling that makes this possible), but I imagine that would also be politically tough if the only reason was a failure to vote.

Comment: On point 3, whilst I agree this is a reason she is being targeted, I can't agree that it was played disastrously. Parliament was wrong (morally, not legally) and in breach of the convention of separation of powers, when it required the government to release privileged legal advice. Within the judiciary, even a supreme court judge does not have the power to require an advocate to breach client confidentiality. It is pretty outrageous that the legislature disregarded this important principle for political reasons, and the govt. was right to stand their ground (albeit at a high political cost).

Comment: @JBentley I have to disagree with your last point. At the very least the full legal advice should have been made available to MPs, otherwise they would be being asked to vote on perhaps the most important matter to come before parliament in half a century without understanding the legal position behind the issue. That would be morally unacceptable.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it could do with some sources.  Today most people who closely follow British politics will know what those points are about, but for posterity and the wider world some sources and pointers would strengthen this answer.

Comment: @Jontia That breaches the most fundamental principle in the Solicitor's SRA Code of Conduct, confidentiality (which overrides even the duty not to mislead the court). The correct solution (as pointed out by the attorney general) is that the opposition MPs could have sought their own independent legal advice rather than compel someone else's lawyer to breach confidentiality. To make an analogy, if we are entering into a contract together and you seek legal advice, it would not be reasonable for me to demand that you reveal your advice. Instead, I should seek my own advice.

Comment: The motion was not against the AG, it was against the *recipient* of the advice. The advice is not given to individuals but to the Cabinet; I would say a more appropriate analogy is if a *company* sought legal advice but some of the directors refused to reveal it to others. The underlying issue is that the Government is not supposed to mislead Parliament, but trust has broken down, and the purpose of forcing the reveal of the advice was to show how Parliament was being mislead.

Comment: @JBentley putting your example into practice you would be the EU. The rest of parliament is still part of me. It might be reasonable to ask parliament to keep the advice confidential, but it should be available to the House. If MPs cannot be trusted not to reveal confidential information, then that is something parliament itself must deal with. It is not a reason in itself to withhold information.

Answer (score 14):

No-one in the Commons is unaware that any other PM would face the same Brexit challenges, to much the same outcome; but this is about a more important long-term principle than that.

To add to others' points, the issue isn't necessarily the details of May's Brexit deal so much as how she went about getting it. Legislatures guard against executives that deny their power. Since taking office, she has on [multiple](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/jan/24/supreme-court-brexit-ruling-parliament-vote-article-50) [occasions](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-46446694) been forced in a ruling to give Parliament or others more of a say in the process, rather than acceding to the usual separation of powers. Even the countless [resignations](https://news.sky.com/story/every-minister-who-has-resigns-from-theresa-mays-government-over-brexit-so-far-11553877) and dismissals factor into this, as an unstable Cabinet composition concentrates any power seized from the legislature. Her government was recently found [in contempt](https://news.sky.com/story/mps-gear-up-for-marathon-five-day-brexit-deal-debate-11571280) for hiding legal advice from them, because of what it had to say about the deal.

Indefinitely [postponing](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/dec/10/theresa-may-postpones-brexit-deal-meaningful-vote-eu) a vote she was very likely to lose, by all appearances because it could damage or end her leadership, after she'd tried to avoid allowing that vote in the first place, was probably the last straw for many MPs.

Comment: This answer is both credible, and also answers the question of "why now" which higher-voted answers mainly don't. The number of letters suddenly increased on a timescale which was completely different to the shambolic incompetence of the government, which has been evident for some time. No one likes to be an ignored, bypassed, spare-wheel at work, and certainly not people with the typical ego and pomposity of a member of parliament.

Answer (score 3):

May cancelled the vote on her deal and went to see EU leaders with a view to renegotiating it, which was immediately rejected. She can delay the vote until late January, but that leaves little time to do anything else if it is rejected and few people think that there is anything she can do to rescue it.

Reading some of the [letters](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-46237174) sent to the 1922 Committee, it seems that most of those MPs are unhappy with May's vision of Brexit and her inability to deliver it. They are concerned that the UK will drift into a bad deal or no deal simply by running out of time, and wish to see someone more to their liking take over.

So in answer to the question, by the time they get a vote on the deal it may be too late.

Comment: In which case, the EU leaders may now expect there is no deal. The current one probably can't pass.