# Is it possible to live as a British/Canadian/Australian while openly disavowing the Monarchy?

Tags: monarchy, constitutional-monarchy, commonwealth

Suppose a natural-born citizen of one of those countries principally objects to the notion of monarchy and in particular is unwilling to swear allegiance to a king or queen - are there any rights or privileges that would be denied to them such as getting an ID, a passport, a drivers license etc. ?

What about a non-natural person otherwise qualifying for citizenship or a passport?

Comment: "a non-natural person otherwise qualifying for citizenship or a passport" What is a non-natural person?

Comment: Lots of comments deleted. Comments should be used to improve the question by providing constructive criticism or requesting clarification. Please do not use comments to answer the question or discuss the subject matter of the question.

Comment: “non-natural person” seems to be incorrect usage in the Question, when applied to humans except for slaves. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_person).

Comment: @Trilarion I suspect that "non-natural" here contrasts with "natural- born," so it would mean surgery someone who has been naturalized or who qualifies for naturalization but hasn't yet gone through with it (presumably in this case because of anti-monarchy sentiment).

Comment: "unwilling to swear allegiance to a king or queen" - I'm British and I've never sworn allegiance to anyone. We don't do anything like the pledge of allegiance in the US (well, at least what's portrayed in schools in films).

Comment: The term "non-natural person" usually means a legal entity such as a corporation. I don't think that's what's intended here.

Answer (score 68):

**TLDR**

From natural-born citizens at least, no, you don't need to swear such allegiance, unless you're doing some very specific jobs. Even in such jobs, possible with some exceptional circumstances, one can be 'anti-Monarchist' without repercussion.

---

I'm British, so I can comment on the "natural-born" part of this question. What I say below applies for such people. I don't know about people applying for citizenship "from outside", but I *expect* similar claims hold.

While personally I have no issue with the royals, I know lots of people who oppose them, some very strongly and openly; I don't remember specific names, but if you look up famous British comedians, say, you'll see that a lot of them go on these panel shows and, if it comes up, have a rant about how much they hate the concept of 'royals'.

*@LightnessRacesinOrbit* points out in the comments, that Jeremy Corbyn, the leader of the opposition party, is such a person. Although he claims that he wouldn't try to remove the monarchy were he in power ([*Independent* article](https://www.independent.co.uk/leadership-debate-latest-jeremy-corbyn-jeremy-paxman-monarchy-not-on-my-agenda-a7762281.html)). I guess he feels there are more important things; but this doesn't restrict him from becoming PM (prime minister), and even as the PM he would meet the Queen weekly -- even if he were to campaign for abolition of the monarchy, he'd still meet her weekly! (Might be awkward...)

Personally, I don't recall (in my 24 and a bit years) ever being officially asked about this. In particular, certainly for a passport or driver's licence I never needed to. [As mentioned by *origimbo*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/20666/8647), to be an MP (member of parliament) you have to swear an oath to the monarch, but that's a pretty specific thing -- much more so than getting a passport. Similarly, police officers swear an oath to serve the Queen (described and cited [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_oath#United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_and_Northern_Ireland)) -- although @*inappropriateCode* points out below that this is not the case in Northern Ireland (which makes sense, culturally).

I think in general the idea that you are allowed to have your own political view is held well above the idea that you have to like the monarch.
As the saying goes, *"it's a free country"*.

Comment: Does the British passport still have a page referring the monarchy in it? There were [calls to remove it](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1562594/Queen-may-be-scrapped-from-UK-passports.html) some years ago, but I don't know if it's still in there.

Comment: This answer only covers half the question; what about people applying for citizenship?

Comment: @Will Yes, you're right. I must confess, after reading other answers/comments, I forgot about the final sentence! Thank you for pointing this out (in a sensible, non-vindictive!) way; let me edit my answer accordingly :)

Comment: The Leader of the Opposition might be a good example to invoke.

Comment: @JJJ having renewed my passport very recently, I can confirm that the page in question and reference to the queen is still in there.

Comment: @JJJ and Carcer -- note that the Queen authorises passports, so she has to be mentioned. Just like with drivers licences, and even I think money. That's why she doesn't have a passport, nor a drivers licence (let's be honest, she has other people to drive her anyway!)

Comment: @SamT for the queen to travel abroad where she isn't queen, she must have her people arrange being allowed in (which I think is common for heads of state). I don't think she'd queue up in regular lines for customs or passport control. As for money, she [has people for that too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duchy_of_Lancaster).

Comment: Yeah, sure :) -- I was just meaning that it's authorised in her name, as the head of state. So this doesn't mean that people have to be pro-monarch to have a passport -- not that you claimed that! I was just pointing out that it's not overly relevant :)

Comment: While generally true, this answer is not correct with regards to a truly republican opinion.  If you were a politician who refused to bend the knee (Sinn Fein) then you are not allowed to sit in parliament, take part in debates, or take a salary.  Corbyn is not legitimately republican, he just pays lip service to the idea, because he still made the oath.  Sinn Fein however do get elected, claim expenses, and visit government (but not the House).  But not being allowed to speak in parliament or have a salary is a big issue.

Comment: Also worth noting army officers must declare loyalty to the monarch, naval officers do not; because the navy has historically been a royal institution, so their loyalty is assumed... not quite with the parliamentarian army.  Also the police in the British mainland must declare their loyalty to the monarch, but those in Northern Ireland don't have to... for obviously cultural reasons.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84310/discussion-on-answer-by-sam-t-is-it-possible-to-live-as-a-british-canadian-austr).

Answer (score 55):

I have been a Canadian my whole life and I do not recall ever being asked to "swear allegiance" to the monarch verbally.

Generally the monarchy is popular in a celebrity kind of way and while there are some anti-monarchists I believe it is not a significant political issue.

Since individual rights are important to Canadians (and I imagine similarly to the people of the U.K. and Australia) political views are not a hindrance to living a normal life for the vast majority of Canadians.

[At this link are people who are openly anti-monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republicanism_in_Canada) and I would guess they have drivers' licenses and passports.

New Canadians have to declare fealty to the monarch when they make Canada's [Oath of Citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Citizenship_(Canada)).

Comment: "New Canadians have to declare fealty to the monarch when they make Canada's Oath of Citizenship." Is there any procedure specified in written form what would happen if a new Canadian breaks that oath, for example by being disloyal to the monarch?

Comment: @Trilarion: how would you define being disloyal? Unless someone commits a specific offence, you're generally free to say what you like.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I mean the opposite of fealty. The Oath of Citizenship of Canada should define what it means by declaring fealty. Otherwise, what is an oath worth, if nobody knows what it means or if nobody cares about it.

Comment: @Trilarion Wikipedia give a good definition: "a promise to abide by [Canada]'s laws and uphold the duties of a [Canadian] citizen" That's what fealty has *always* meant (change Canada / Canadian for whichever group is headed by whomever you are swearing fealty to)

Comment: @Caleth I don't think this is the definition. Look at the text of the oath on Wikipedia "I swear ... that I will be faithful and bear true allegiance to Her Majesty ... and that I will faithfully observe the laws...." You swear two things. The first thing is being faithful and bearing true allegiance (whatever this is) to her Majesty and all her successors and the second is to faithfully observe the laws. One does not necessarily have to do anything with the other and the second does not look like the explanation of the first. Just my interpretation. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Functionally, disloyalty to the monarch is anything that carries the punishment of losing citizenship. I'm not Canadian, so I don't know whether there is anything in that category. At a guess, joining an army that is fighting against Canada.

Comment: @Trilarion: unless you can have your citizenship revoked for breaking the oath, I'd argue that it is entirely symbolic. After all, _anyone_ within a country's jurisdiction will (in theory) be punished just the same for breaking the law, whether they're a citizen or not. (A separate question would then be: if the citizenship oath is entirely symbolic, why is it a requirement?)

Comment: I'm born a Canadian. The only time I can remember saying anything about the queen was as a boy scout (God, Queen and Country). I also naturalized as an American citizen in my late 40s.  At that point I took an oath to _absolutely and entirely renounce and abjure all allegiance and fidelity to any foreign prince, potentate, state, or sovereignty, of whom or which I have heretofore been a subject or citizen_.  But, Canada doesn't recognize that as a renunciation of Canadian citizenship, so I remain a Canadian.  Am I breaking my oath by keeping a Canadian passport; I know I'm not breaking the law

Comment: I've  attended the Canadian citizenship ceremony as a guest. For what it's worth, the Citizenship oath is sworn in a large group and I don't think anyone is watching all that carefully as to what words are being spoken- though they do very clearly warn participants that they will not receive their certificate if there is doubt they took the oath. My friend, a Scottish chap, was actually a bit salty about having to swear an oath of fealty to the Queen.

Comment: I'd agree that it _is_ entirely symbolic, but you still must swear fealty to the Crown (not necessarily the Queen-she won't be around for ever) when you take the oath of citizenship. It's always been a source of annoyance to me, that my mother & sisters (naturalized) had to do so, but I (Canadian by birth) didn't. "Functionally", disloyalty to the Queen is not punishable, let alone by revocation of citizenship. @Flydog57: No, you're not breaking your oath. Since the days "fealty" meant something, a transfer of fealty has always been possible. It's not as if you swore fealty to the US in secret

Comment: The citizenship oath was the subject of a [dismissed appeal](http://www.ontariocourts.ca/decisions/2014/2014ONCA0578.htm) in Ontario a few years ago. In essence, the court ruled that the oath is not to the Queen personally, but is "a symbolic commitment to be governed as a democratic constitutional monarchy unless and until democratically changed."

Comment: I'm surprised no one else has talked about Quebec province yet! I've heard many time people publicly saying "Death to the Queen!"... Monarchy here either leave people indifferent or loathed.

Answer (score 40):

This is a complete non-issue in the UK. For example, the leader of the opposition in Parliament, Jeremy Corbyn, has openly refused to sing the National Anthem when attending high profile, televised, public events such as a memorial service commemorating the anniversary of the Battle of Britain in WWII.

It's hard to imagine any public figure "getting away with" that sort of behaviour in the USA!

Of course many people (including Corbyn, going through the formalities of parliamentary procedure) may sometimes do things that they don't believe in - but the vast majority of the UK population is never *forced* to make any declaration of allegiance to, or show any respect towards, the monarchy, the national flag, and similar national symbols.

Comment: It's true to an extent, but refusing to swear loyalty to the monarch will cause problems.  "non-issue" is not true.  Corbyn still swore an oath to the monarch.  Sinn Fein did not, so they do not sit in parliament or get a salary.  Similarly if you refused to swear loyalty to the monarchy you'd not be allowed to join the army or police in the mainland.  The police in Northern Ireland don't swear an oath to the monarch, and curiously Naval officers don't as their loyalty is assumed given that the navy is a royal institution, unlike the parliamentarian army.

Comment: "It's hard to imagine any public figure "getting away with" that sort of behaviour in the USA!" Political culture does not translate well. American loyalties are (generally speaking) to the nation and the Constitution, with the flag as a symbol of both - as some athletes who "took the knee" found to their dismay. While the institution of the presidency is respected in a way the monarchy is not, speaking as an ignorant, outsider Yank, I find it hard to believe that the sort of vituperation widely applied to the current orange-haired president would be much appreciated towards the Queen Mum...

Comment: ... And likewise, I'd be quite surprised to hear of any public criticism offered up against the royal family to match the (short-lived, to be sure) #rapemelania incident.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast You don't get many people reacting to her political statements, because she doesn't make any. You *do* get people who are reacting to the *behaviour* of various royals, particularly Phillip and Charles. The political mudslinging all goes at MPs (particularly the Cabinet and Shadow Cabinet)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Public criticism and pushing to _rape someone_ are two different things. You probably wouldn't see the latter in the UK only because we are generally a little better behaved than that. Not much, but a little.

Comment: I think some of the criticism of Princess Diana (by the minority who *didn't* think she was some sort of goddess) was just as vituperative, and much longer-lived, than anything directed at Melania - who after all is only a target for 4 or 8 years. And Prince Charles is regarded (by some) as just as much a buffoon as your orange-haired president. But nobody is likely to want to *rape* the 92-year-old queen, I guess ;)

Comment: In a public opinion poll in 2017, over 50% of the respondents stated that they would prefer Prince William as the next monarch rather than the heir to the throne, Prince Charles. So much for "respect" for individual *members* of the royal family, as opposed to the institution itself. And don't forget punk rock's contributions to popular culture at the time of the Queen's Jubilee (1986) - in particular, the Sex Pistols.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Again, political culture doesn't translate well. "Public criticism and pushing to rape someone are two different things" indeed, but it was clear at the time that #rapemelania was not an actual call to action. It was, rather, a very successful example of expressing outrage in terms that leave no doubt of the level of outrage being expressed. In fact, it was so successful that it was squashed within hours. Sort of like the bumper sticker/button "Where is Lee Harvey Oswald Now That We Need Him?". First showed up for Nixon (and you can still buy it), but more so.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, the Queen Mum died in 2002.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Most royals don't have any influence in how the contry is run, the majority of their duties are just ceremonial formalities. The most they can do to upset people is make some politically incorrect comments ([Prince Charles is famous for making such comments](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-03-03/prince-philip-was-not-a-racist-indigenous-performer-says/9504278)), so in most cases nobody cares enough to complain. The royals simply aren't in our minds the way politicians are because they don't have the impact that politicians do. (Also the Queen's mother is dead.)

Comment: I don't believe it _is_ a complete non-issue for naturalized citizens. The "Oath of Allegiance" is the same for those public servants who must swear and for newly naturalized citizens, and it's been around for 150 years.

Comment: Re:  "It's hard to imagine any public figure "getting away with" that sort of behaviour in the USA!"   Um... Literally the Declaration of Independence.   It's a giant list of reasons why the King of England sucks  We've not only do it, we've been getting away with it for 200 years.   In serious though,  the U.S. Oath of Office is to the Constitution, not to any leadership figure.   The U.S. Government is also legally not able to compel singing for the National Anthem nor Saying the Pledge of Allegiance+

Comment: + however, it's also not compelled to require citizens to support anyone who deems it necessary to refuse to do those things.   It just won't arrest them for it on top of any consequences society chooses to inflict.

Answer (score 26):

British person here, [swearing an oath of loyalty to the monarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Allegiance_(United_Kingdom)) only happens if you join government service of some kind (millitary, police, etc). Otherwise it almost never comes up. While I quite like the royals, a lot of people don't like them and are free to do so.

Comment: The UK actually has [citizenship ceremonies](https://www.gov.uk/citizenship-ceremonies) for new citizens which do require taking an oath of allegiance.

Comment: This link says "You need to attend a citizenship ceremony if you’re 18 or over and have successfully applied to become a British citizen." -- the OP is about natural-born citizens

Comment: @JJJ: Have you got a source that says this oath of allegiance is to the monarchy rather than to the country? The only details it gives are "This means you promise to respect the rights, freedoms and laws of the UK." which doesn't rule out the possibility of monarchy being invoked but certainly doesn't confirm it.

Comment: @SamT not exclusively. This answer says it is only used for joining goverment jobs, which is untrue.

Comment: @Chris only hearsay (EU citizens who applied for permanent residence). I'll see if I can find the actual text later today, should be in there.

Comment: @JJJ sure, yes, I agree; I was meaning *your link* was about people becoming citizens, not natural-born ones. Apologies for the lack of clarity

Comment: Perhaps the most relevant form of government service is to be a Member of Parliament (MP), where you must either swear or affirm an oath of allegiance to the monarch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Allegiance_(United_Kingdom). So if you were wanting to peacefully overthrow the crown via election to parliament and debate, you'll have to be somewhat hypocritical.

Comment: @Chris I added the oaths and a little info in a separate answer.

Comment: is this answer unfinished?

Comment: Just to add that I didn't need to make any oath as a UK civil servant. Then again, I do get an extra day's holiday to celebrate the Queen's birthday, so my view on monarchy has changed!

Comment: I think there's a lot of examples missed in this answer, and it would benefit from elaboration.  Like the fact Sinn Fein don't sit in parliament besides getting elected as MPs because they won't accept British sovereignty or swear an oath to a monarch, and that while the police and military do swear oaths to the monarch, this varies.  Northern Ireland's police don't, and curiously Naval officers don't either.  The latter case owing to the Navy being a royal institution so loyalty to the crown is assumed, unlike the Parliamentarian army.

Comment: Northern island isn't actually part of Great Britain, but good point about naval officers

Comment: It might not be about 'liking' or 'disliking' so much as an ideological position about affording everyone in society a choice about what they do with their lives.

Comment: @Josh It's the "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland" remember.  Great Britain refers to the island which England, Scotland, Wales live on.  The United Kingdom is the act of union between England and Scotland.  Hence why the official title expands to specify Northern Ireland as being included.  People born within Northern Ireland's borders can claim both British and Irish passports and thus citizenship.  I know I did.

Comment: @Strawberry what choices do citizens in a monarchy have that citizens of a republic don't? The only thing I can think of is that republic citizens can aspire to be the head of state someday

Comment: @Caleth I was thinking specifically of the future head(s) of state, whose lives, while privileged, seem essentially predetermined.

Comment: @Strawberry You don't have to accept or keep the crown. See [Edward VIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_VIII)

Comment: @origimbo Almost all the vows in the article linked contain the phrase "according to law". Anyways, Parliament claims universal authority on making laws, and will not feel bound even by a hypothetical bill about preserving the Monarchy. Also, there are many MPs that took the oath, but in their  own way, like Tony Benn.

Answer (score 24):

## New citizens

Others have discussed most about those having citizenship from birth. I will attempt to answer this part of your question:

> What about a non-natural person otherwise qualifying for citizenship or a passport ?

### United Kingdom

To become a UK citizen, one must take an oath of allegiance. The [text of the oath (from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_citizenship#United_Kingdom) is as follows:

> I, [name], [swear by Almighty God] [do solemnly, sincerely and truly affirm and declare] that, on becoming a British citizen, I will be faithful and bear true allegiance to Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II, her heirs, and successors, according to law.

This oath is to be taken in one of the final steps in becoming a citizen, during a so-called [citizenship ceremony](https://www.gov.uk/citizenship-ceremonies).

### Other Commonwealth countries (e.g. Canada)

Other Commonwealth countries have similar requirements. For example, that first Wikipedia page also lists the oath for future Canadian citizens:

> I swear (or affirm) that I will be faithful and bear true allegiance to Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth the Second, Queen of Canada, Her Heirs and Successors, and that I will faithfully observe the laws of Canada and fulfil my duties as a Canadian citizen.

Or in French, [of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_bilingualism_in_Canada):

> Je jure fidélité et sincère allégeance à Sa Majesté la Reine Elizabeth Deux, Reine du Canada, à ses héritiers et successeurs et je jure d'observer fidèlement les lois du Canada et de remplir loyalement mes obligations de citoyen canadien.

Comment: From your wikipedia link I went to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Allegiance_(United_Kingdom) which discusses the oath in more detail including various people that swear it (police officers and members of the judiciary being the ones I found).

Comment: "...I will be faithful and bear true allegiance to Her Majesty..." Is there a commentary existing somewhere what this actually means? What should or shouldn't one do to be faithful and bearing true allegiance to Her Majesty? What would happen if one fails to do that?

Comment: @Trilarion you might want to consult the [British Nationality Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_nationality_law), though I'm not sure it explicitly answers those questions. If anything, it might be a good question for Law.SE.

Comment: @Trilarion it's only meaningful if you are a dual national. The UK has treaty obligations to not render anyone stateless.

Comment: @Caleth they can still put nationals in jail. There used to be (not sure if the UK still has any) [lèsé majesté laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A8se-majest%C3%A9#United_Kingdom).

Comment: @JJJ read the link: "The final prosecution for this offence had occurred in 1715"

Comment: @Caleth yes, but if I understand correctly the law was only retracted in 2010. I was merely making the point that there are other things a state can do short of making a person stateless. Indeed some other countries still have these laws and some enforce them as well.

Comment: I swore the oath around the time of tampongate. Weird. But I got over it.

Comment: Australia doesn't mention the monarch in its citizenship pledge. (There is a specific answer about it already).

Answer (score 13):

The other answers comprehensively cover the UK and Canada cases. I'll offer the Australian perspective, as a naturalised Australian citizen.

Contrary to Canada, the Australian citizenship pledge does not pledge allegiance to the Queen. It it a common misconception though, so much so, that when one of my friends is about to become a citizen, I tease them by asking: "are you ready to offer your allegiance to the Queen?". They are pleasantly surprised when they learn [the actual text](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/citi/pathways-processes/citi/australian-citizenship-pledge). There are two versions of the pledge: including the phrase "under God", or not.

> From this time forward, [under God,] I pledge my loyalty to Australia
>   and its people, whose democratic beliefs I share, whose rights and
>   liberties I respect, and whose laws I will uphold and obey.

The current version of the pledge was introduced in 1994. [Older versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Allegiance_(Australia)#Pledge_of_Commitment_for_citizenship) did offer allegiance to the King or Queen.

Moreover, the members of the Parliament and members of the Armed Forces [still have to make an oath (or affirmation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Allegiance_(Australia)) that includes allegiance to the Queen. But in practical terms, I do not believe that this stops them from expressing anti-monarch views and sentiments.

A fact that supports this belief is that the previous prime minister of Australia, [Malcom Turnbull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malcolm_Turnbull), came to political prominence in the late 90s leading the [Republican movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Republic_Movement) in Australia. In other words, an anti-monarchist politician reached the highest political position in the country.

Answer (score 9):

H2ONaCl's answer gives a good Canadian perspective, there is a similar list for the UK [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republicanism_in_the_United_Kingdom), which lists Members of Parliament, prominent journalists and media personalities.

MORI polls cited on the Wikipedia page show around 20% of those sampled expressing republican views.

The current Leader of the Opposition (Jeremy Corbyn) is one of the people mentioned, so it's not only possible, but quite a popular viewpoint in the UK.

It's true that Members of Parliament swear an oath to "Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II, her heirs and successors, according to law", but this has been interpreted as an oath to the person and not the office, or with the emphasis on "according to law", which does not preclude holding republican views. There are some more (or less) artistic variations on this idea from republican politicians listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Allegiance_(United_Kingdom)#Republican_parliamentarians).

Comment: Corbyn did however make the Oath of Loyalty to the Queen, which the OP specifically says they won't do. Sinn Fein MPs do not take their seats in the house precisely because they refuse to do this.

Comment: @JackAidley Sinn Fein MP's refuse to take their seats in Parliament because they don't accept that Northern Ireland should be part of the UK at all. That is a much broader issue than *personal* allegiance to the monarchy.

Comment: @JackAidley - Good point - editing.

Comment: @alephzero Sinn Fein would neither sit in British parliament; thereby accepting British authority in Ireland, nor swear loyalty to any monarch; being republicans. They're still active politically on both sides of the Irish Sea though.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers clearly address the practical aspect of the question, namely they correctly suggest that it is possible (and common) to live in the Commonwealth while openly disavowing the monarchy.  Nonetheless, the formal legal situation may be much less favorable.

Indeed, under [the Treason Felony Act 1848](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treason_Felony_Act_1848) of the United Kingdom, it is **treason felony** to "compass, imagine, invent, devise, or intend" to deprive the Queen of her crown in *any* of her dominions and countries (whether or not you are located in the United Kingdom yourself).  The maximum punishment for this crime is life imprisonment.

[This section of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treason_Felony_Act_1848#Discussions) provides some discussion of *the Guardian*'s attempt and failure to challenge this Act in 2001, as well as some more activity in 2013 that indicates that the law is still in force.  See ["Calling for abolition of monarchy is still illegal, UK justice ministry admits"](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2013/dec/13/calling-abolition-monarchy-illegal-uk-justice-ministry) in *the Guardian*.

The last charges under this act appear to have been in 1972.  Those charges were reduced to the lesser charges of *seditious utterances*, which itself was a crime in the same vein.  This charge appears to have been abolished, [except for aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedition#United_Kingdom), addressing another aspect of your question.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting there are certain circumstances, that a non-natural citizen can acquire British citizenship without swearing the Oath of Allegiance. As I was a minor when I acquired my British Citizenship, my mother didn't want me to skip school (as she could get [fined](https://www.gov.uk/school-attendance-absence/legal-action-to-enforce-school-attendance) for doing so) to attend the ceremony and informed the council that she would be picking up my certificate as well as her own, which they were perfectly happy to do.

Comment: What may have been possible then may (no pun intended) no longer be possible now considering the [Home Office hostile environment policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Office_hostile_environment_policy).

Comment: I would have supposed that taking part in a citizenship ceremony would be an acceptable reason for skipping school, if announced (and possibly proven) beforehand.

Comment: In this particular case, being under 18 is the relevant circumstance. ["*You need to attend a citizenship ceremony if you’re 18 or over and have successfully applied to become a British citizen.*"](https://www.gov.uk/citizenship-ceremonies)

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be at least three different issues being discussed here.

One is, essentially, whether you are obliged to accept the authority of the law, the constitution, and the government of the country, which has the monarch as its titular head. The answer is: yes, you are. If you behave in a way that flouts that authority then you will end up in prison.

Two is whether you are obliged to say that you like this system. Answer: no, you aren't. Even those who swear allegiance are only agreeing that they will go along with the system, not that they actually like it or are prepared to defend it.

Three is whether you like the individual currently holding office. That's almost totally irrelevant. Except that the British system is actually quite flexible, and there have been quite a few occasions over the centuries that a monarch, or proposed monarch, has been unacceptable to the people (or the barons) and has been quietly sidelined. It could happen again.

Answer (score 1):

In the 1990s, if an Australian boy or girl became a Scout, they had to swear "to do my duty to my God, and to the Queen of Australia." However these days they can choose instead to swear "to be true to my spiritual beliefs, to contribute to my community and our world."